# Angular select array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects called `presentations`

I'm trying to use them in a [select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) element, but it's not working. The select box just comes up blank with nothing in it.

I think it might be because it wants either an array, or an object, not an array of objects.

I'm doing:

```
<select ng-model="secondPres" ng-options="p.name for p in presentations" ></select>
```

And I can console.log my `presentations` array and get this:

```
0: Object
name: "club"
origName: "club"
slide: "1"
tenant: "grant"

1: Object
name: "2slide"
origName: "club"
slide: "1"
tenant: "grant"

2: Object
name: "CT_Stress_Test"
origName: "club"
slide: "1"
tenant: "grant"
```

So what's going on?

Here's my controller code. The console.log that produces shows what I have above is at the bottom. expand() is called on `data-ng-init`

```
var socket = io.connect('https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.net:3000');

$scope.versions =[];
$scope.presentations=[];
$scope.secondPres;
$scope.expand = function(){
    console.log("expand hit " + presentation1);
    var urlToSign = presentation1;
    var urlToSign = urlToSign.replace(/^(.*)\/Slide\d_v\d.PNG(.*)/,"$1"+"");
    console.log("url to sign = " + urlToSign);
    socket.emit('getSignedSlidesFromUrl',urlToSign);
    socket.on('signedUrls',function(data){
        console.log('got back signedUrls' + data);
        $scope.slides=data;
        $scope.$apply();

        var re = /^.*\/\/.*\/.*\/(.*)/;
        var fileName = re.exec(urlToSign)[1];

        for(i=0;i<presentationList.length;i++){
            var url = presentationList[i];
            console.log(url);
            var re = /^.*\/\/.*\/(.*)\/.*$/;
            var re2 = /^.*\/\/.*\/(.*)\/.*\//;
            var re3 =/^.*\/\/.*\/.*\/Slide(\d*)/;
            var fileName2 = re.exec(url)[1];
            var customerName = re2.exec(url)[1];
            var slideNum = re3.exec(url)[1];

            $scope.presentations.push({name:fileName2, origName:fileName, tenant:customerName, slide:slideNum});
        }
        console.log($scope.presentations);
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Is this array coming from an external service without scope digestion ?

Comment: @lib3d No, I don't think so, but I don't know what you mean by scope digestion

Comment: @lib3d +1, that's what it looks like to me too.  Try calling $scope.$apply() after your for loop.

Comment: @CraigSquire Yep. That was it. I forgot about apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your just missing a `$scope.$apply()` after your `for` loop to make Angular see your new array items.  Or wrap the entire contents of the event handler in a function passed to `$scope.$apply()` similar to the snippit here.

```
 socket.on('signedUrls',function(data){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log('got back signedUrls' + data);
        $scope.slides=data;

        var re = /^.*\/\/.*\/.*\/(.*)/;
        var fileName = re.exec(urlToSign)[1];

        for(i=0;i<presentationList.length;i++){
            var url = presentationList[i];
            console.log(url);
            var re = /^.*\/\/.*\/(.*)\/.*$/;
            var re2 = /^.*\/\/.*\/(.*)\/.*\//;
            var re3 =/^.*\/\/.*\/.*\/Slide(\d*)/;
            var fileName2 = re.exec(url)[1];
            var customerName = re2.exec(url)[1];
            var slideNum = re3.exec(url)[1];

            $scope.presentations.push({name:fileName2, origName:fileName, tenant:customerName, slide:slideNum});
        }
        console.log($scope.presentations);
    });
    });
```

Comment: I just added `$scope.$apply()` to the end of my method, since I only plan on this socket being hit once.